# loki reject_old_samples_max_age vs retention_period

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

We're using latest loki, but confused how to define the retention properly:

What is the difference between:

- reject_old_samples_max_age
- retention_period

What takes the priority?

**In the example below, will the data be deleted after 168h or 336h?**

```yaml
limits_config:
      enforce_metric_name: false
      reject_old_samples: true
      reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
      max_cache_freshness_per_query: 10m
      retention_period: 336h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data will be deleted after 336h because the "retention_period" parameter defines that. The "reject_old_samples" (true or false) and "reject_old_samples_max_age" parameters are related to if old log entries received by Loki should or shouldn't be accepted by the tool and how old these log entries can be and still be accepted.

See more information about the Loki configuration [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/).